# Is it possible to download Bootstrap Themes in Drupal?If yes,then how can we edit the HTML,CSS and JS of the theme to suit my preferences?

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap, drupal

I have to edit an existing website on Drupal.I wanted to replace the current theme of the website with a Bootstrap theme but I am finding it difficult to do so.In addition, I also wanted to tweak the code of the downloaded theme to suit the client's preferences.How do I proceed with this?

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You download and install a base theme, create a [sub-theme](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/creating-a-drupal-8-sub-theme-or-sub-theme-of-sub-theme) and do your changes there. It's pretty well documented.

You may try this base theme for Bootstrap 4: https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap_barrio

Or this base theme for Bootstrap 3:
https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap